# Filter log on final letter in string

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a below requirement to filter a word.

My logs will be reporting with codes `TML2345I`,`TML8383E` & `TML9929W`.

I want to filter the errors only with strings which have the last character as `E`.

Please suggest how can we get this using `sed` or `awk` or any other utilities.

Note: the first 3 characters (`TML`) will not change and the remaining characters will be changing as per specific errors.

Comment: How about some example input and output?

Answer (score 4):

Using Gnu Awk:

```
awk '/\<TML[0-9]*E\>/' log
```

Match any word (field) on a line (record) that begins with TML, has any number of digits and then ends in E.

Comment: that even looks cool.

Comment: @mikeserv [hipster bird...](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3321/6761) :)

Comment: is that your ad?

Comment: @mikeserv Yep :p